# readHTMLTable in R - skipping NULL values

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, null

I am attempting to use the R function readHTMLTable to gather data from the online database at www.racingpost.com. I have a CSV file with 30,000 unique ids which can be used to identify individual horses. Unfortunately a small number of these ids are leading readHTMLTable to return the error:

Error in `(function (classes, fdef, mtable)`  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function **‘readHTMLTable’** for signature ‘"NULL"’

My question is - is it possible to set up a wrapper function that will skip the ids which return NULL values but then continue reading the remaining HTML tables? The reading stops at each NULL value.

What I have tried so far is this:

```
ids = c(896119, 766254, 790946, 556341,  62736, 660506, 486791, 580134, 0011, 580134)
```

which are all valid horse ids bar the 0011 which will return a NULL value. Then:

```
scrapescrape <- function(x) {      
  link <- paste0("http://www.racingpost.com/horses/horse_home.sd?horse_id=",x)      
  if (!is.null(readHTMLTable(link, which=2))) {
     Frame1 <- readHTMLTable(link, which=2)
  }
}

total_data = c(0)
for (id in ids) {
  total_data = rbind(total_data, scrapescrape(id))
}
```

However, I think the error is returned at the if statement which means the function stops when it reaches the first NULL value. Any help would be greatly appreciated - many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could analyse the HTML first (inspect the page you get, and find a way to recognise a false result), before reading the HTML table.

But you can also make sure the function returns nothing (NA) when an error is thrown, like so:

```
library(XML)

scrapescrape <- function(x) {

  link <- paste0("http://www.racingpost.com/horses/horse_home.sd?horse_id=",x)

    tryCatch(readHTMLTable(link, which=2), error=function(e){NA})

  }
}

ids <- c(896119, 766254, 790946, 556341,  62736, 660506, 486791, 580134, 0011, 580134)

lst <- lapply(ids, scrapescrape)

str(lst)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `rvest` you can do:

```
require(rvest)
require(purrr)
paste0("http://www.racingpost.com/horses/horse_home.sd?horse_id=", ids) %>% 
  map(possibly(~html_session(.) %>% 
                 read_html %>% 
                 html_table(fill = TRUE) %>% 
                 .[[2]], 
               NULL)) %>% 
  discard(is.null)
```

The last line discards all "failed" attempts. If you want to keep them just drop the last line